# Why does maximized Remote Desktop no longer restore via drag?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Previously, in Windows 7, I was able to "restore" a maximized Remote Desktop window by dragging the blue tab from the top of the screen down toward the middle.  (Restore is the term for visible but not maximized.)

This feature is still available on my laptop and on my home machine--just not on my work machine.  I would uninstall recent updates (.NET Framework 4.5.1 and a 4.5.1 security update); however, it is a work machine and I would prefer not to uninstall updates, if possible.

Note that I can still drag down other maximized windows (Word, Excel, Outlook, Visual Studio, etc.)

I tried checking Windows | Accessibility | Prevent windows from being automatically arranged... and then back off again but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same thing. Did you ever find out anything about this? I find it very irritating!

Comment: It's annoying, I know.  Yes, I did solve the problem a little while ago and, as usual, I forgot to write down what I did.  Darn!  I promise to report back if I remember.

Comment: Oh no! I really hope you remember, this is driving me nuts! My IT Dept gave me suggestions but none helped. I've looked all over the "Options" stuff in Remote Desktop Connection, nothing helps. They suggested setting the screen size in that dialog to one click below Full Screen, but that didn't help either. *sigh* I'll keep checking back here now and then, thanks in advance for trying -- I hope you remember!

Comment: Now that you mention it, it might have been related to the window placement settings in either default.rdp or all my saved .rdp files. Try either deleting default.rdp, which is in your Documents folder, and run without loading a specific .rdp file, or I can publish what I have. Let me know.